# Can I use VLANs (or virtual interfaces) to create a firewall on single pysical interface?

Tags: networking, router, routing, firewall

As my router/gateway to the internet I have an (NB6) SFR-provided, very barebones wifi router. I have to use this to connect to the internet, for auth reasons. This facilitates a mandated 192.168.1.0/24 network.

I have a TP-link ax53 that has garbage ipv6 and firewalling support (but can also be turned into access point mode). As a (second) wifi router, this creates another LAN on 192.168.0.0/24 with the SFR box as gateway.

I have a mini pc with Alpine Linux installed. It only has one physical ethernet port. For now, I can't get a second physical ethernet port via USB.

I'd like to use the Alpine box to take the traffic from the AX53, filter it through a series of firewall rules (preferably defined in UFW), and forward requests to and from the AX53 network.

Is this possible using VLANs or some other dummy or virtual interfaces with routing rules to allow for seamless NAT/forwarding? If so, where would I start and what would be an example setup. I can seem to get this to work properly myself.

Comment: One physical interface is enough for routing. You just create logical subinterfaces, as in `eth0.10` for VLAN 10, `eth0.20` for VLAN 20 etc. Each subinterface gets its own IP address in the appropriate VLAN range, and system is configured to route. Here's Alpine Wiki [VLAN page](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Vlan).

Comment: You'll probably want to set up dhcp+nat on the Alpine box (example: https://cylab.be/blog/221/a-light-nat-router-and-dhcp-server-with-alpine-linux), and disable dhcp on the router. Clients use Alpine as their default gateway, Alpine uses router as its gateway (static), and done. Don't even have to use sub-interfaces or different subnets, but they can be helpful for organizing firewall rules/zones. VLANs are not really necessary (and the router would need to support having multiple IDs assigned to one port).

Comment: @Cpt.Whale If only one physical interface is available, how does one route between 2 subnets w/o subinterfaces and VLANs?

Comment: That's just assuming you keep stuff on the same subnet to make it simple. You can have multiple gateways on the same network, but should only have one dhcp server handing out assignments.

Comment: If you want to physically separate clients from the router, then yeah subnetting and/or vlans are in order, which require multiple logical "legs" for your single Alpine interface. For more examples and better descriptions, look up "Router on a stick" configurations

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Dang. I got excited there'd be another way I'm not aware of... would've come in handy as my router doesn't support VLANs...